# TSA lock reset button stuck and now lock button is also stuck

Tags: luggage, tsa

I have a VIP skybag (I believe this does not matter). It has a 3-number TSA lock built into the suitcase. I know the combination to unlock, let's say it's 345. Recently it was locked and while there was a different number on the combination lock the reset/set lock button was pressed.

Since then the reset/set lock button is pressed (stuck) and the lock button also does not unlock. Any pointers on how to unlock it? I am thinking of unscrewing the lock from inside of the suitcase but it seems quite a hassle, as I may have to assemble it back. Let me know if there is any other option to unlock it from the outside.

Comment: Probably more suitable for diy.stackexchange.

Comment: It surely worked. Tapping with a metal spoon.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem during my recent visit to Hyderabad India. Initially at home, I tried all combinations from 000 to 999, but it didn't work... finally I took it to VIP shop. He examined and tapped the lock with a stapler a couple of times,  to make the reset lock unlatch. After trying 000, he moved to 111, when it opened. Then the lock was reset to my preferred combination.  He charged INR Rs.200 for the services.

Comment: Welcome to the site, thanks for your personal experience answer. Pity we can not copy it from your story as we do not know where and how hard to hit the lock.

Comment: I had the same problem. Following the example of the guy at the VIP shop, I tapped the lock with the only tool available - a metal spoon - and the reset button unlatched. Thank you for sharing the answer and saving me some time and money.

Comment: I was skeptical of this method before trying but it indeed works. I took a spoon as well and banged a few times. Both out of hope it would work but mostly out of frustration that the lock on a 1200€ suitcase I bought the day before was giving me grief. Nevertheless - crisis averted and after this it worked fine to set the code.

Comment: For reference - my bag is an aluminium Tumi bag with two TSA007 locks built into the frame. The bag is called "19 Degree Aluminum Extended Trip Packing Case" and I banged all over the lock many times and suddenly it worked.